# Is there a way to open and modify a python file in a virtual machine of google cloud platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, google-cloud-platform, cloud, training-data

I just started to use cloud to do training for my deep learning program. For now every time I modified my local .py file I have to remove the old one in the remote virtual machine of Google Cloud Platform and upload the new one. I  am just curious if there is a way that I can actually open the .py file in the remote visual machine through the command line? That would be very high efficiency.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you share some of the code you use and which command line commands you've tried? That would help understand the exact nature of your use-case.

Comment: @ubershmekel thanks. actually I'm looking for command line to open&see a file in the remote visual machine so I think it is not relevant for what my code looks like.

Comment: I just wasn't able to understand your initial question. Part of the problem was you called it "visual machine" and I had no idea which platform you were talking about. I'll give you a few options in an answer. If I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I guess you are referring to Virtual Machines rather than "visual".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit a file on a machine you can SSH into there are many potential solutions.

- Use scp to copy files. E.g. `scp mylocalfile ssh://my-host-address/myfolder`
- Use ssh mounting solutions: [How do you edit files over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407287/how-do-you-edit-files-over-ssh)
- Edit using `nano your-file-to-edit` (my favorite) https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/
- Edit using `vi` or `vim` http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial